# Trying to Append a List Element with A String without using Replace/Mapç

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to append to a list, the element is a string, and I want to replace it with another string, but this is the error I'm getting

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'
```

so if my list is [['test']]

```
string = 'new'
```

I click list.append[i][j].append(string)

then the list is:

```
[['new']]
```

I can't use replace or map for the project, my current code is:

```
board[i][j].append(game)
```

Comment: So you want to relpace an existing value in the list with another value?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to replace, you can do:

```
board[i][j] = game
```

If you want to append, it would be just:

```
board[i].append(game)
```